# How to cure black magic and evil eye

Tags: sihr

Assalamu alikum wa rahmatullah,

What is the Quran and Sunnah based way to cure black magic and evil eye? Is there any way to find out the source of black magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eat seven Ajwa dates in the morning, than he or she will not be affected by magic that day, [Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/54200).
As for the evil eye, the Ma'udhatan (Surat Al Falaq and Annas), [Source](http://sunnah.com/nasai/51/67).  As for a cure, take a bath, [Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/254270).  A du'a that Gibril (peace be upon Him) used to recite on the Prophet (May Allah's peace and blessings be upon Him) when he fell ill is:

> بِاسْمِ اللَّهِ يُبْرِيكَ وَمِنْ كُلِّ دَاءٍ يَشْفِيكَ وَمِنْ شَرِّ
>   حَاسِدٍ إِذَا حَسَدَ وَشَرِّ كُلِّ ذِي عَيْنٍ

-

> In the name of Allah. He may cure you from all kinds of illness and
>   safeguard you from the evil of a jealous one when he feels jealous and
>   from the evil influence of eye

[Source](http://sunnah.com/urn/254240)

Comment: thanks! by 'source' i meant that, can we know who did the black magic?

Comment: I do not think so. Allah A'laam.

Comment: I tried the 7 Ajwa dates in madian, this method does not work. but the jinn does not like those dates.

Comment: @Erik there is one way I know you can see the magician/jinn. That is to summon it in your dreams see this link:http://www.quran.mu/la-roqya-par-ben-halima-abderraouf-2-of-2.html

Comment: @Erik what you see in your dreams gives you clues, like if yuo see re-occuring dreams of hairs, then probably hairs were used in the magic